# How to preselect intellisense entry in VS2019?

Tags: ide, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

For example I have a local `StringBuilder` variable named `builder`. On VS2015, typing **`bui`** will show something like this:

[image]

However, when doing the same in VS2019, it's like this:
[image]

The reason I would want the same behavior as 2015, is if I press enter key, or '.' key, it would automatically accept the preselected entry `builder`. On the otherhand, when on 2019, pressing enter/. would add a new line/. and the output would be `bui` + new line/. , as compared to 2015's behavior `builder` on enter, and `builder`. upon pressing '.'. Also, I tried toggling the setting under Options → Text Editor → C# → IntelliSense → Enter key behavior → 'Only add new line on enter after end of fully typed word' and it did not produce the output I wanted.

How or what options should I set to achieve the same behavior as VS2015?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Make sure **Toggle Completion Mode** option is disabled in your machine.

In VS2019, Go `Edit menu=>Intellisense=>Toggle Completion Mode`. Click it to change its status.

**Unchecked:**
 [image]

**Checked**(blue rectangle)**:**
[image]

Then make sure you choose the `Only add new line on enter after end of fully typed word`.

I think the `Toggle Completion Mode` option is the main cause of your issue. Unchecked this option then the `Enter behavior` in Tools=>Options can work.